# What single word describes the action of tapping a spoon against a glass?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

What is it called when someone taps a glass with a spoon in order to seek attention at a party or at the dining table?

Comment: Calling the assembly to order?

Comment: I think it's "tapping a glass".  (To "tinkle" means to pee.)

Comment: Do you want the name of the *action* (tapping a glass)? Or do you want a word that refers to the *purpose* of the action (to draw people's attention)? Please specify, thanks.

Comment: Yes I want name of the action.

Comment: @HotLicks That's British informal. 'Make or cause to make a light, clear ringing sound'

Comment: @Sprottenwels - Yes, it's *very* informal in the US.

Answer (score 5):

A single word for making a sound by gently hitting a metal object against a glass one could be **clink**:

> If two **glass or metal objects** clink, or if you clink them, they make a short ringing sound when they are hit together:
>   *Spoons clinked against the crockery.*

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/clink_1))

Here's a real-world usage example from a book called "Mama's Little Book of Tricks":

[image]

([Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZeKBAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq=clink%20a%20glass%20with%20a%20spoon&source=bl&ots=DrIoYzTyJZ&sig=o3G5PyQM9dhBPq-fBbU3bz995-I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBoQ6AEwADgKahUKEwjO8qH2w93IAhXFOhQKHYUrA4o#v=onepage&q&f=false))

If a phrase is OK, you already mentioned it: it's *tapping a spoon/fork/etc. against the glass*.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, **tinkling a glass**.

> **TINKLE**
>
> : to give forth and make a succession of short, ringing sounds, as a small bell
>
> : to make known, call attention to, attract or summon by tinkling [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tinkle)
>
> : make or cause to make a light, clear ringing sound:  [no object]:
>   *cool water tinkled in the stone fountains*; [with object]: *the maid tinkled a bell* [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tinkle)
>
> : to make or emit a tinkle or a sound suggestive of a tinkle [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tinkle)
>
> : to make light metallic sounds, as those of a small bell: v.tr to cause to tinkle; to signal or call by tinkling. [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tinkle)
>
> *He returned to the sitting room and turned down the music, while Guy tinkled a glass to gain everyone's attention;* *The sound of a spoon tinkling against a glass again brought a hush to conversations*.
>
> [A Year at Nethercombe Ley](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ERm8AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA372&lpg=PA372&dq=%22tinkled+a+glass%22&source=bl&ots=X0FzIY3xCp&sig=t8S9kwQMc2xA-GuAOyjccW2OCL4&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMIt5HopsPdyAIVyNcaCh1_ZQXA#v=onepage&q=%22tinkled%20a%20glass%22&f=false)
>
> *Hal tinkled a glass to get everyone's attention. "I've got some hot news for you guys."*
>
> [The Happy Accident](https://books.google.fr/books?id=N34KIeFGveoC&pg=PA219&dq=%22tinkled+a+glass%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBmoVChMIivC-rsfdyAIVgkoUCh2_-Ao_#v=onepage&q=%22tinkled%20a%20glass%22&f=false)

Comment: Cool. I had no idea that was a second meaning. Unfortunately most of us know a third meaning.  If somebody "tinkled" to get a waiter's attention, I would expect the waiter to come with a mop.

Comment: Man, and here I always thought it meant a woman peeing.

Comment: I considered *tinkle* myself, but yeah, it has strong connotations of peeing in informal speech.

Comment: @A.P. Sure, in informal speech...